# How to get the indirect formula to not return an absolute cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to use an indirect formula in a conditional format formula and I'd like to control the `$` references that are returned by the indirect formula.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Not Interested",$16:$16,0)),INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Not 
Interested",$16:$16,0),4),"1","")&ROW(J17)))
```

Essentially, I'm looking for the row that contains the "Not interested" column header and then I want  to format the entire row red if that column has an "x" in it.

```
INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Not Interested",$16:$16,0),4),"1","")&ROW(J17)))
```

The above part of my formula is correctly finding the row and using `row(J17)` will allow me to move through my cells in the conditional format formula but the only problem is `Indirect(K17)` returns `$K$17` when i need it to return `$K17` or even just `K17` is there a way to change that?

Comment: I think you're using Conditional Formatting incorrectly. The "Applies To" range is what makes it check every row (or cell, really) you want to check. I think I can make the formula you *should* be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use indirect at all if you use absolute references judiciously:

```
=INDEX(17:17,MATCH("Not interested",$16:$16,0))="x"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this did the trick and avoids the clunkiness of my formula - thank you!

Comment: This is a better formula than mine but I think you need `MATCH("Not interested",$1 6:$16,0)` with the **match_type** set to 0 for an exact match. Once other text starts appearing on row 16, the formula as-is will probably break.

Comment: @Engineer Toast  <facepalm> Yes, of course, I've modified the formula in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Conditional Formatting is evaluated independently for every cell in the "Applies To" range. You want to write the formula so that it'll work for every cell in that range.

```
=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&MATCH("Not Interested",$16:$16,0),FALSE)="x"
```

[image: Conditional Formatting]

[image: Results]